# PhoneGap - Updating the apk file in Google Play says "Your APK's version code needs to be higher"

Tags: android, cordova, google-play

I am having a problem, when I try to update an `APK` production file in `android`, it says

"Your APK's version code needs to be higher than 19."

My app is built with phonegap and I have the following code in my config.xml .

```
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "com.rodriguezcab.release"
    version   = "20.0.1">
```

Though I have `version = "20.0.1"`, it keeps saying "Your APK's version code needs to be higher than 19." Any solutions?

Comment: Get your problem figured out?

Comment: not yet, i am still looking for a slolution..

Comment: Did changing the versionCode as I suggested not work?

Comment: i use jquery mobile and phone gap to develop the app. i couldnt find AndroidManifest.xml. can u help?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593328/how-to-solve-your-apks-version-code-needs-to-be-higher-than-2-in-google-play

Answer (score 3):

You can set this in `config.xml` (in the root of your cordova project). This is better than setting in 'platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml' because platforms folder can be deleted.

In `config.xml` set this in the root (widget) node:

```
versionCode="20"
```

Note this changed since previous versions (don't you love that?) when it was:

```
android-versionCode="20"
```

Comment: Also note it doesn't just need to be different, it needs to be a greater number. For example I accidentally added a digit to my version number, and there's no going back.

Comment: Thanks, I needed to add the versionCode attribute to fix my rejected PhoneGap Build app.

Answer (score 2):

Check `platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml`

There you will see `android:versionCode`

This number needs to be incremented for new versions of the app. Don't get this confused with `android:versionName` that gets changed from the config.xml file when you do your build.