# Upload failed You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 2

Tags: android, apk

According to this answer [How to solve "Your APK's version code needs to be higher than 2." in Google Play's Developer Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593328/how-to-solve-your-apks-version-code-needs-to-be-higher-than-2-in-google-play) I have just changed the version code from 2 to 3 and it failed to upload the build.

This is my old manifest before I uploaded the apk

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mypackage name"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="28"
    android:versionName="1.0028" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
        .....
```

here is the new version code which I have to upload on android developer console. See my menifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mypackage name"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="2.0001" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
        ......
```

I dont know whats the issue. Any help?
[image]

Comment: If changing the version code does not work try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66878818/8383332

Answer (score 144, accepted):

```
android:versionCode="28"
```

Your previous `versionCode` was 28. You should increment it by 1 to 29.

```
android:versionCode="29"
```

Presumably, your previous app versions were 1 through 28. By releasing with versionCode 3, you are conflicting with a previous version of your app that was already released with this versionCode.

Comment: This number is used only to determine whether one version is more recent than another, with higher numbers indicating more recent versions. This is not the version number shown to users

Comment: For anyone else who might be confused, please note that this is not the sdk version but your app version code,

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what is the path of that file?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira ./app.json

Comment: For Flutter, see the answer from @Vaibhav_Welcomes_You.

Answer (score 250):

For people who use Android Studio the problem may be solved by editing  `versionCode` and `versionName` in `build.gradle` instead of `AndroidManifest.xml`.

e.g.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.my.packageId"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 2      <-- change this
    versionName "2.0"  <-- change this
}
```

Comment: Can you read AndroidManifest.xml from build.gradle? Doesn't make sense to have values twice.

Comment: This is the answer. Tha what happend here is that the gradle is the the one incharge to build the proyect, so it overwrites the versions

Comment: make sure the versionCode is a whole number and you sync after the change.

Comment: React-native solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/51003398/6747265

Comment: When using Flutter you do not need to change this in those files but in `pubspec.yml`. There is a `version` property that default looks like `1.0.0+1`. The number after `+` corresponds to the `versionCode`. So if you want to raise to version code `3` you need to change the `version` property in `pubspec.yml` to `1.0.0+3`

Answer (score 61):

In my case it a simple issue. I have uploaded an app in the console before so I try re-uploading it after resolving some issues.
All I do is delete the previous APK from the `App Bundle Explorer` (formally called `Artifact Library`)

Comment: I uploaded a version through the Google Play Console, then deleted before publishing, and uploaded again and got the OP error.  I thought I had deleted it, but it was still present in the Artifact Library.  Delete from there then I could upload...

Comment: This is the answer.

Comment: `Artifact Library` is now `App Bundle Explorer` on right hand side bar of the console.

Comment: Thank you !  I didn't understand how it was possible since my number are generated incrementaly

Answer (score 25):

if you are using **ionic framework**, go to **config.xml** file and change the **"version"** attribute in the **"widget"** tag. increase the version number. then rebuild, sign and upload ur apk to play store. that fixed my problem.

Comment: Thanks. I will Just to add few details. I changed version attribute in widget tag from **0.0.1** to **0.0.2**. After executed `cordova build --release android` command, this change modified AndroidManifest.xml in two attributes, from **android:versionCode="1"** to  **android:versionCode="2"**  and from **android:versionName="0.0.1" ** to **android:versionName="0.0.2"** in manifest tag.

Answer (score 24):

This error appears when you try to upload an apk that has same version values as the one already on playstore.

Just change the following in your build.gradle file => versionCode and versionName

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.my.packageId"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 2      <-- increment this by 1
    versionName "2.0"  <-- this is the version that shows up in playstore, 
                           remember that the versioning scheme goes as follows.
                           first digit = major breaking changes version
                           second digit = minor changes version
                           third digit = minor patches and bug fixes.
                           e.g versionName "2.0.1"
}
```

Answer (score 24):

**(For Flutter App)** You need to use a different version code for your APK or Android App Bundle because you already have one with version code 1.

Don't be panic...

You need to change in **Flutter Version** from **pubspec.yaml** file and **Version Cod**e from **local.properties** file.

First go to your **pubspec.yaml** file. The first three lines should be name, description and version of App.

*Before Release -*

For you the version might look something like this:

**version: 1.0.0+1**

So before creating an apk for release (for update your exiting app on **Google Play Console** i.e for new update) make sure you increment this number by 1. (You should increment it as there's no requirement on increment step) .

***Solution***

Just change that version to (As per your need )

**version: 1.0.1+2**

And Second if

**flutter.versionCode** in **Project -> android -> local.properties** is

**flutter.versionCode=1** then change it or upgrade it to the **flutter.versionCode=2** or any other greater number than previous code.

And finally release the app as per documentation.

Comment: So for a Version code following _Semantic Versioning_, where it is `major.minor.patch+build`, Play is _only_ looking at the last `build` component?  (That isn't a bug?)

Comment: Correct yes. checkout "Changing the apps version number" in the docs 
 - https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#building-the-app-for-release

Comment: Works for Flutter. Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

Sometimes the PlayStore encounters a bug when you upload an APK during a Release creation, and you are stuck because you cannot upload the same APK again, for the current draft release. You get the error "Upload failed..."

The solution is to go to the **Artifact library** menu, under **Release management** and to delete the draft artifact. Once this is done, you will be able to upload the APK again, and to finish your release.

Hope it will help others...

Ben

Comment: This. This happens if you start uploading a binary and cancel it even if the upload process is finished on the UI. You have to delete the previous bundle.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using Building Standalone Apps with Expo, the versionCode error might creep up owing to the fact that the standard `app.json` config only has a reference to the `version` property.

I was able to add a `versionCode` property under `android` as follows:

Sample App.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "sdkVersion": "29.0.0",
    "name": "App Name",
    "version": "1.1.0",
    "slug": "app-name",
    "icon": "src/images/app-icon.png",
    "privacy": "public",
    "android": {
      "package": "com.madhues.app",
      "permissions": [],
      "versionCode": 2 // Notice the versionCode added under android.
    }
  }
}
```

Detailed documentation: https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/workflow/configuration/#versioncode

Comment: Dude Thanks for the tip fixed my problem with expo and google V1

Answer (score 7):

In Android Studio 1.1.0, change `versionCode` in `build.gradle` for `Module: app` and don't necessarily change `versionName`:

```
android {
...
    defaultConfig {
...
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0"
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just as Martin Konecny's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24772442/2431281) said, you need to change the versionCode to something higher.

Your previous version code was `28`. it should be changed to `29`.

According to the [document on the android developer website.](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html) a version code is

> An integer value that represents the version of the application code, relative to other versions.

So it should be related(by related I mean higher) to the previous versionCode as noted by the document:

> you should make sure that each successive release of your application uses a greater value.

As mentioned again in the document

> the android:versionCode value does not necessarily have a strong resemblance to the application release version that is visible to the user (see android:versionName, below)

So even though this is the release `2.0001` of your app, it does not necessarily mean that the versionCode is `2`.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Android Studio, you could go:

Build -> Edit Flavors

And change the Version Code and Name from there.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

if you are using phonegap / cordova applications, just edit your config.xml and add the android-versionCode and version in the widget.

> <widget id="com.xxx.yyy" version="1.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"
>   android-versionCode="100001"
>   version="1.0.1">

Answer (score 3):

***2021! For Flutter developers!***

in your pubspec.yaml:

[image]

Detailed answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56970752/12279445)

Don't put feedback after!

Answer (score 3):

Last Updated 18-12-2021:

1. Go to Google Play Console if you want to delete or revised same version and choose “App Bundle Explorer”:

[image]

2. Pick the version:

[image]

3. If you have build version that not been released yet, you can delete it. Delete options not showed when you don’t have pending release.

Or if you just simply ignore pending release, you can use new build. Go to pubspec.yaml and set this:

> version: 1.4.17+67

That’s for example if you have version: 1.4.17+66 before.

Comment: what is maximum number for version code? can it be 1.4.17+9999  ?

Comment: “Warning: The greatest value Google Play allows for versionCode is 2100000000.” stated at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html

Answer (score 1):

If you get this error for your Flutter App's Android APK, in your app/build.gradle file under defaultConfig {}

comment out

```
versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
versionName flutterVersionName
```

and add

```
versionCode 2
versionName "2"
```

or "previous version code" + 1.

Answer (score 1):

I received the same error while uploading a flutter app to playstore simply change the version code in **pubspec.yaml** worked for me. may be try changing the version code e.g from +1 to +2 and then rebuild the apk using

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```

and upload all the apk's to the playstore for your users.
Next time when you want to push an update make sure to update the version code to +3 and so on.

> Note: that the version code and version name are different you can see
> that in **android/local.properties** file.
> e.g version: 1.0.0+2
>
> version is 1.0.0 and verison code is +2

Answer (score 1):

just change the version code in yaml file.

```
version: 1.0.0+2 --> 1.0.0+3
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems because you have already uploaded APK file of version 3 to Google Play Store. And again you are uploading apk with same version. So this issue has been occurred.

So for solution you need to change your version name and version code (increment with 1)and run application once and after export it upload to Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting same error again and again, 
 
Finally I uploaded the apk file manually using **Google Play Console** as shown in screen shot. 
Under App Release, You select the button "CREATE RELEASE" shown in the screen shot and upload your apk file from `/android/app/bin/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had something like this in my `AndroidManifest`,

```
      javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            arguments = [
                    'androidManifestFile': 'app\\build\\intermediates\\merged_manifests\\debug\\processDebugManifest\\merged\\AndroidManifest.xml'
            ]
        }
   }
```

here the 'androidManifestFile' location is wrong, changed it to

```
"androidManifestFile": "$projectDir/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml".toString()
```

everything worked

Answer (score 0):

In my **app/build.gradle** file , version code was like this:-

[image: build.gradle(app module) file]

In place of **versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()** , i replaced it with as
**versionCode 2**

Answer (score 0):

**For flutter and bitbucket pipelines.**

You could use the command  `flutter build apk --release --build-number=YOURVARNUMBER`

`--build-number=4` lets you assign the build number 4 when you compile apk file.

This can be used to increment the number in a pipeline build. For instance if you use some kind of continues integration pipeline. Like bitbucket pipelines, you can write
`flutter build apk --release --build-number=$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER` this way each build will automatically have an incremented number, rather then you having you write this number yourselfe.