# You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 1

Tags: android

i know this has been ask [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772407/upload-failed-you-need-to-use-a-different-version-code-for-your-apk-because-you)

The correct answer is to change the version does not solve my problem 
id did added this two lines in my manifest

```
 android:versionCode="2"
 android:versionName="2.01"
```

but then when i clean and build using android studio the generate the apk again then upload the same error happend ..

**Note:** I did check that it is the correct file that i try to upload in the developer console

Comment: You should increase your version code by 1 i.e make it 3. Hope it works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload failed You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772407/upload-failed-you-need-to-use-a-different-version-code-for-your-apk-because-you)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the build.gradle file check if you have versionCode like

```
 defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

because if you have mentioned versionCode in build.gradle file then it will overwrite the values in manifest file. Please make sure if you have mentioned version code here then you have updated here also.

Answer (score 2):

Change it in the `build.gradle` file of your app module in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Remove those from your manifest. Go to File>Project Structure> And either flavors or build types (don't remember and don't have my pc on me). Set the version name and version code from there.