# Expo React-Native Android build not updating Version Code for Google Play

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I built a React-Native android app and uploaded to Google Play, which worked fine.

Now I have a new build I am trying to upload (had no issues uploading to itunes Connect), and Google Play is giving me this error:
"You need to use a different version code for your APK or Android App Bundle because you already have one with version code 1."

After each build, I have updated the version in app.json, and I have tried updating the version in package.json as well. I've done a directory-wide search for 'versionCode' and there are no instances. A directory-wide search of 'version' turned up over 2,000 results, and I scrolled through all of them, and did not see anything specific to android build. And I did NOT have an issue with iOS build.

I have tried publishing the app first using Max Expo XDE, and I am building it in command line with "exp build:android".

I have the following in my app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Placeholder",
        "sdkVersion": "27.0.0",
        "privacy": "unlisted",
        "orientation": "portrait",
        "icon": "./assets/img/AppIcon.png",
    "version": "0.3.4",
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.placeholder.placeholder"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.placeholder.placeholder"
    }
  }
}
```

and my package.json is as follows (and npm install has been run):

```
{
  "name": "placeholder",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest-expo": "~27.0.0",
    "react-native-scripts": "1.14.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "expo": "^27.0.1",
    "native-base": "^2.4.3",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-27.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-svg": "^6.3.1",
    "react-navigation": "^2.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.1.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 70):

I also experience this issue, I resolved it by adding versionCode to my app.json under android. For instance,

```
"android": { 
      "versionCode": 2 
}
```

Notice that the '2' does not have quotation marks.

if you need know more about versionCode, see this documentation.

[versionCodeOnAndroid](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning)

Comment: This is the correct answer - detailed here - https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/workflow/configuration/#versioncode

Comment: perfect. Thank you so much. Expo should make it more explicit.

Comment: If you ejected your app, you'll need to edit your `build.gradle`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71564798

Answer (score 7):

needed to add "versionCode" to the "android" section of app.json specifically...

Answer (score 5):

If you are using expo bare workflow then changing app.json won't work. You have to rather go to `android > app > build.gradle` and increase both versionCode and versionName by 1

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing! This was exactly what I needed that the other answers didn't cover.

Comment: Great.  Adding the versionCode to app.json didn't work for me using expo.  This did.  Thanks.

Comment: If you are using bare workflow with expo you need to run `yarn expo prebuild`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using vanilla react native (without expo) then changing app.json won't work. You have to rather go to build.gradle and increase both versionCode and versionName by 1

Answer (score 1):

while building and delivering to testflight you need to update version before build. If you're annoyed with this as much as I am, you could use the nodejs simple script, lets call it build.js:

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');
const { exec } = require('child_process');

let config = require('./app.json');

let t = new Date().getTime();
let backup = 'app.' + t + '.json';

// make some backup
fs.writeFile(backup, JSON.stringify(config)); 

let v = config.expo.version;
v = v.split('.');
let x = parseInt(v[v.length - 1]);

// add to last part of version, update to your needs
v[v.length - 1] = (x + 1); 
config.expo.version = v.join('.');

// write new config
fs.writeFile('app.json', JSON.stringify(config, null, 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using these configurations worked for me:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "APP_NAME",
    "description": "APP_DESCRIPTION",
    "slug": "SLUG_NSME",
    "version": "1.1.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],

    "android": {
      "package": "com.company_name.project_name",
      "versionCode": 2 // just change/add this line
    }
  }
}
```

Find complete Guide here: [expo documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/) and [Play Store Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html).

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches.

1. If you are using managed workflow :
   Go to app.json file under android obj property add "versionCode" : 1
2. If you are working with bare workflow: Then go to android>app>build.gradle.
   Then search for versionCodem versionName and update the values with the version you want.

Answer (score 0):

According to Deploying to App Stores [1](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/app-stores), you need to follow the instructions from Building Standalone Apps. The "versionCode" is indeed referenced in [2](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/building-standalone-apps.html) and it is an option specific to the Android section: [3](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/configuration.html#versioncode).

Answer (score 0):

In the file app.json or app.config.json you have to add the new versionCode, this version is internally for Google, if you need show a version to user, you can add versionName:

```
"android": {
...
"versionCode": 2,
"versionName": "0.0.1"
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

go to `app.json` set the version code in your `expo.android.versionCode` it must be type of `number`

Answer (score 0):

For me helps add `versionCode` at `app.json`.
Exemple:

```json
"expo": {
"android": {
      "versionCode": 2,
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
}
```

Comment: highlighting for code need 3 (not 4) backquote (`) characters :)

Answer (score 0):

You need add `versionCode` at `app.json`:

```
"android": {
      "versionCode": 2, // Increase this one
    },
```