# Is there a way to change version code in flutter

Tags: flutter, build.gradle, version

I'm setting up the app to upload on play store but the play console gives error-You need to use a different version code for your APK or Android App Bundle because you already have one with version code 1.
   I tried changing the version code in android>app>build.gradle and even in local.properties but after hot reload or run command the local.properties automatically changes back to flutter.versionName=1.0.0 and flutter.versionCode=1.
   It may be because of error in my build.gradle file as it shows red mark and give can't resolve symbol for properties,rootProperties,getProperty etc. and the same error with flutter.buildMode=release in local.properties
   How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of changing Gradle files, you need to make the changes in `pubspec.yaml` file.

It is located in the root directory of your project.

```yaml
version: 1.0.0+1
```

> A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
>
> followed by an optional **build number** separated by a +.

Google Play should accept your APK generated with increased **build number**.

Answer (score 4):

This is briefly mentioned in the [official documentation for releasing your app](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#updating-the-apps-version-number).

For Android and iOS, you need to update the "version" value in the pubspec.yaml file.

```
version: 1.0.0+1
```

For Android, the first piece ("1.0.0") corresponds to the version name whereas the piece after the + corresponds to version number.

For iOS, the first piece represents the CFBundleShortVersionString and the piece after the + represents the CFBundleVersion.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53570575/flutter-upgrade-the-version-code-for-play-store) has more information.

Comment: Just a small correction; the number after `+` represents the version code.