# updating flutter app to newer version from older version in play store

Tags: flutter, dart

Few days back published flutter android app on play store and now I want to update that app in play store and so have made changes in the code and but now I am confused that whether I have to generate a new key using the same procedure I did while publishing the app for first time(generating the key and then run flutter build app bundle) or I have to follow some other procedure.
Kindly help, millions of thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

all you have to do is update the `version` in `pubsec.yaml`, and you just you have to build the apk/aab again then release the updated version on the playstore as you did before.

for more information on upgrading version check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56970752/11385677)

as a bonus if you want to display a message to your users the your app got updated then you can use this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/upgrader)