# Release APK version not updating

Tags: android, flutter, apk

I´m writing a flutter application and it is currently on version **0.7.0**, I already specified the version in `pubspec.yaml` and the Debug APK is already on the updated version, but the release APK it´s not updating, even after 'flutter build apk' or 'flutter run --release'.

Release APK:

[image: Release APK]

*As you can see on the image the Version name is 0.6.0 instead of 0.7.0*

Debug APK:

[image: Debug APK]

*In debug apk the version is 0.7.0*

pubspec.yaml:

[image: pubspec.yaml]

- Project repository in [github](https://github.com/PedroGXV/phoso)

Comment: is running `flutter clean` gives any help?

Comment: i tried 'flutter clen', but still not updating the version

Comment: try running `flutter pub get` first. Then check your `versionName` and `versionCode` in the `local.properties` file in android folder.

Comment: so, I runned pub get, then on the local.properties the versionName is 0.7.0 but it didn´t have the versionCode. I clicked on the AndroidManifest.xml that shows in the .apk screen and the versionCode is diferent, idk if it´s auto-generated, I tried to change the AndroidManifest inside Android folder but the final AndroidManifest still with version 0.6.0

Comment: try change the version to `version: 0.7.0+1`. Or like @jordan-kotiadis says, try `version: 0.7.0+2`.
This seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53570575/flutter-upgrade-the-version-code-for-play-store

Comment: you need to change the version in your `pubspec.yaml`. change `version: 0.7.0` line to `version: 0.7.0+2`

Answer (score 1):

*So, even after changing codeVersion dind´t worked.*

### Solution

But I founded a solution, just deleted the build bin and then runned `flutter build apk`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change also the version code from 1 to 2

Comment: can you teach me where I change the version code? I´m new in flutter/dart.

Comment: you to build.gradle and you will change flutterVersionCode with the value 2

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it with running `flutter build apk` in flutter project and open android flutter project in android studio and generate singned apk in android studio