# Uploading new APK to the play store getting failed

Tags: android, google-play

I have already uploaded the beta version, with version code 1,
Now I m trying to upload the new version in Production mode. I am changing the versionCode from 1 to 2 and versionName from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1 
Then I am genereating the signed APK.

But when I m trying to upload the apk, its showing "You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 1."

Please help me to get rid of the prob.
(Do it need to delete the previous signed apk file which i have created at the time of generating signed apk and create again)

Comment: You apparently didn't rebuild the APK with the manifest changes, or you're not uploading the APK you just built. There's a tool you can use to check the versionCode of an APK (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593328/how-to-solve-your-apks-version-code-needs-to-be-higher-than-2-in-google-play).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely changed your `versionCode` directly in your Manifest file. But if you use Android Studio, final Manifest file is **generated** and some parts may be  overwritten during manifest merging phase (see [blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/25/hey-where-did-these-permissions-come-from.html) on what it is). So highlight your `app` module, press <kbd>F4</kbd> and bump version code on `Flavours` tab.

[image]