# While uploading an APK, I'm getting an error for the version code

Tags: android

My old code was

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.webservice"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >
```

And I changed it to

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.webservice"
 android:versionCode="2"
 android:versionName="2.2" >
```

But still getting the same error

Comment: Look out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593328/how-to-solve-your-apks-version-code-needs-to-be-higher-than-2-in-google-play

Comment: Please post the screen shot of Error.

Comment: are you using Android Studio?

Comment: Clean your project and run it. if it is same problem post your complete Log.

Comment: @USKMobility -  Yes i'm using Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to set your build.gradle file (App module)

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
         ...
         versionCode 2
         versionName "2.2"
         ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Glad to see this parth parikh. Thank you.

Comment: Done! :) Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Your versions should be like this -

```
 android:versionCode="2"
 android:versionName="1.1"
```